# Publishing Office365 API app into customer's Active Directory

Tags: visual-studio-2013, office365-apps

I have developed an ASP.NET MVC5 app for Office365 using latest update of the Office 365 API Tools for Visual Studio. The app works fine with my own development Office365 site.

I understand that Visual Studio has registered the app in my Active Directory for me.
What I don't understand is how I am supposed to allow my customers to use this app with theirs Office 365 installations.

Somehow they are supposed to register the app in their Active Directory - that is the step I don't know how to explain to them.

Is there an automated way to provision the app registration to a customer's Active Directory?

The same way Visual Studio did it when I started the development? How did it do that? Through what kind of API?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your app in Azure AD to be multi-tenant. You can do this through the Azure Management portal. (Applications > [Your Directory] > Applications > [Your Application] > Configure).

Once the app is multi-tenant, your customer can navigate to the app and log in to trigger the common consent flow. Assuming that your customer has the permissions necessary to consent and allows the app to access their data, the customer will then be able to use the app with their Office 365 subscription.